# Questions about buying a Buddha statue

Tags: buddha, statue

How important is the hand gesture of a Buddha statue? 
I heard in a video that I should definitely get a Dhyāna Mudrā (Meditation) statue or a bhūmisparśa (calling the Earth to witness / touching the Earth) statue to deepen my practice... Which is unfortunate because I'm on a tight budget and found a good deal I'd like to snag on an Abhayamudrā (gesture of fearlessness/giving refuge) statue.

Secondly, is it okay to buy one with a (small) crack in the plate behind the head (not sure what it's called)? As some have pointed out that could symbolize impermanence... I just want to make sure it's "kosher".

Lastly, can I keep my statue in storage until I have a shrine or at least a clean and appropriate room? Or should I wait to until I have a good place to set it out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answers might depend on the school of Buddhism, and vary. There were several different answers to this questions -- [Is it wrong to buy a Buddha statue in Thailand from a Buddhist point of view?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8485/254) -- perhaps from different views or traditions. Might you want to edit to clarify which tradition or type of practice you're asking about?

Comment: I practice Therevada Buddhism and Mahasi style Vipassana. I would like a statue for inspiration and eventually a shrine when I have space

Answer (score 2):

For home decorating purposes, the statues hand gestures, condition or placement probably has some importance.

For buddhist practice, the above really has no importance at all.

(If you could elaborate on what you want to accomplish, it could be easier to answer your question).

Comment: I practice Therevada Buddhism and Mahasi style Vipassana. I would like a statue for inspiration and eventually a shrine when I have space

Comment: This is the absolute answer. Even for the decoration purposes, the Mudrā literally is a matter of preference. Usually, Dhyāna Mudrā is the most peaceful and soothing posture of all. Take a look at the [Samadhi Statue @ Mahamewuna Garden, Anuradhapura, Sri Lanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samadhi_Statue).

Answer (score 1):

Spend time shopping for a Buddha image. Find one that inspires you, not others.

For this writer the face is the most important feature, next to size. He always has a good meditation kneeling in front of the twenty foot image at the local temple, even on Poya day. Besides size this image also has a wonderful face.